# Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use. Pop up while running Docker image httpd

Tags: docker, apache, httpd.conf

Error on Terminal regarding docker image httdp

[image]

How to solve the error?

I want to run index.html which uses the docker image httpd through IP address `http://127.0.0.1/` which is Apache2 default pages

Comment: Welcome to SO.. 
As it said, the port `80` already being in use. You can't use the same port. Choose different one.
Also see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)